# Null pointer exception in search Java

Tags: java, eclipse

```
//TestEmployeesProgram driver with menu & object array.
import java.util.*;
public class TestEmployeesProgram {

public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int MAX = 7;

    Employee employee[] = new Employee[MAX];

    int choice,k;
    String name;
    boolean notFound;

    employee[1] = new Manager("Joe Bloggs","gdr",4,32.5);
    employee[2] = new Admin("Mary Jennings","nnv",35.3,88.5,34.3);
    employee[3] = new Clerk("Brian Jones","bbl",42.4,78.5,23.5,45.3);
    employee[4] = new Manager("John Bloggs","gvr",5,33.5);
    employee[5] = new Admin("Bridget Jennings","nvv",45.3,98.5,36.3);
    employee[6] = new Clerk("Jack Jones","bbb",43.4,78.5,23.5,47.3);


    //Initial Read
    choice = showMenu();

    //Continue Until 4/Exit
    while (choice != MAX)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1://Manager

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Manager){ //use of string method instance of.


                    System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2://Administration

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Admin){
                System.out.println(employee[k].toString());

                }
            }
            break;

        case 3://Clerk

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota","Units Sold");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Clerk){
                System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                }
            }
            break;
```

This case in the switch statement gives me the `NullPointerException`. I have checked everything to see if it's initialized correctly, but can't seem to find the problem.  Also, the search function bypasses the name search to get default message if name isn't found. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

```
        case 4://Name search

            System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
            name = console.nextLine();

            k = -1;
            notFound = true;



            while ((k < MAX-1) && (notFound))
            {
                ++k;
                if (name == employee[k].getName()){

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota","Units Sold");
                    System.out.println("\n==================================================");

                    System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                    System.out.println();
                    notFound = false;
                }


            }//end of case 4 while.
             if (notFound){
                System.out.println("Employee name not found\n");
            }
            break;

        case 7://exit
            System.out.println("Program exiting...");
            System.exit(0);

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid menu choice 1..3 of 7 to Exit");    
        }//end of switch

        //sub read 
        choice = showMenu();

    }//end of while 
}//end of main

//Menu method for employee selection.
public static int showMenu()
{

    int choice;
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Employee Program Menu");

    System.out.println("1.Show Manager pay details ");
    System.out.println("2.Show Admin pay details ");
    System.out.println("3.Show Clerk pay details ");
    System.out.println("4.Search by employee name ");
    System.out.println("7.Exit");

    System.out.print("Enter option: ");
    choice = console.nextInt();

    return choice;
}
}
```

Comment: you have many sequential new lines, wow, it means too many lines of code! amazing!

Comment: Were you able to get it running in the debugger?

Comment: What about the 0-indexed value?

Comment: Did you try to walk through the program step by step using the built-in debugger?

Comment: Nuull pointer exception is always comes inoto the place where incorrect statement not initialized and users alvays forget to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not set any value at `0th` index, so `if (name == employee[0].getName()){}` generate exception as it try to access `employee[0].getName()`.

you should set value to index 0 as array starts with index 0 and ends with size -1 ...

```
employee[0] = new Manager("Joe Bloggs","gdr",4,32.5);
employee[1] = new Admin("Mary Jennings","nnv",35.3,88.5,34.3);
...
employee[6] = new Clerk("Jack Jones","bbb",43.4,78.5,23.5,47.3)
```

Comment: yup this is the answer (and wel spotted my eyes must be tired not to spot missing [0] lol

Comment: @BrianVarley arrays always* start at [0] - *someone is going to pull me up on some language that chose to start array indexes at 1 but hey

Answer (score 0):

Might be out of shape in Java, but, aren't you forgetting to set the new Employee at employee[0] ?

Because in case 4 you start with k being equal to -1, and then increment it to 0, but you don't have an Employee at employee[0] at all....

Answer (score 0):

*edit* After taking a second look, you do this all over the place. So go over your code, and make sure your array is initialized properly. You also might try using named constants for your switch statement, I find they assist in readability (and if you're a student like me, not losing marks for magic numbers).

```
    final int MANAGER = 1;

    final int CLERK = 2; 

    switch(choice)
    {
          case MANAGER: foo;
              break;
           case CLERK: foo;
              break;
    }
```

This is your problem code. When the flow of control reaches the if statement, k is equal to zero, and there is no 0th element of your array, so java throws the null pointer exception.

Also for future reference, try looking in the actual error that the compiler gives you. The compiler gives you a line number, which should allow you to track down the error pretty easily. Java is really nice to you when it comes to null pointers, where c++ will just keep running, using whatever value it finds at the bad location.

```
        k = -1;
        notFound = true;



        while ((k < MAX-1) && (notFound))
        {
            ++k;
            if (name == employee[k].getName())
```